# Django Google log-in/sign up not working even though django-oauth

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-oauth

Following [this guide](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-google-oauth/) to add google sign-in/sign-up to my django app.

Added all the code and it all seemed to be working until the very end when I got this error.

[image]

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/....
```

However, i visit my credential screen I do see the url correctly reported. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved itself after 1h. Probably google taking time to deploy changes in credentials